# How to click an element that is not visible in cypress

Tags: html, automation, cypress

I am trying to click an action menu option and getting this error in cypress:

```js
Timed out retrying after 4050ms: cy.click() failed because this element is not visible:
<div id="pay-off-holiday-option" class="ng-star-inserted">...</div>
This element <div#pay-off-holiday-option.ng-star-inserted> is not visible because its parent <div#ngx_poppperjs_63.ngxp__container.ngxp__animation.popper-actions> has CSS property: display: none
Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.
```

I have tried adding `force:true` on the click and it just moves the menu weirdly, rather than clicking on the element.

Here is how the dom looks like:

[image]

Comment: What is the selector that you are using? Add that to the question.

Comment: How does your menu become visible to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have information on how you can workaround this problem.
Add optional 'option' param.

```
Element.click({force: true});
```

There you can find more information: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click#Usage